# LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to use bcrypt to secure users password, but when i am creating new user in database i receive this error: "LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt"

what i did till now:

1. i have placed a gem in the Gemfile 
   `gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.11'`
2. i installed it 
   `sudo bundler install`
3. bcrypt is in the gem list

> ```
> $ gem list bcrypt
> *** LOCAL GEMS ***
> bcrypt (3.1.11)
> ```

4. i have restart the server

> sudo service apache2 restart

5. i added new user in rails console

> ```
> $ rails console 
> Running via Spring preloader in process 21100
> Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.0)
> irb(main):001:0> User.create(username: "user1" , password: "pass123", password_confirmation: "pass123")
> You don't have bcrypt installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
> LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt
>         from app/models/user.rb:2:in `<class:User>'
>         from app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>         from (irb):1
> ```

And as you see it didn't work!

6. i tried to uninstall and install bcrypt again => same result
7. i have tried other version of bcrypt => same result
8. i added `bcrypt-ruby` to gems => same result
9. i used gem `install bcrypt --platform=ruby`  and `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.5', :require => 'bcrypt'`
   => same result
10. i updated all the gems => same result
11. i built built native extensions manually

> ```
> cd [path to gems folder]/gems/bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4/ext/mri
> ruby extconf.rb
> make
> sudo make install
> ```

=> same result

12. (waiting for your suggestion)

Thank you in advance for your help. I hope this question, with your answers will help people with same problem in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. i was searching for it almost 2 days!

kill all the processes with name spring using the pkill command as follows:

```
  $ pkill -15 -f spring
```

open a new terminal and :
       bundle exec guard
is it gave you error "bundler: command not found: guard" dont worry. just be sure you have installed bycrypt by `gem list bcrypt` 
install bundle

```
sudo bundle install
```

then restart your server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

> now it works!